# TinyMCE - How to get the complete markup where the cursor is

Tags: tinymce, innerhtml

I'm using

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().innerHTML;
```

and it gives me what I'm expecting

```
<li>cell number 1</li>
```

but sometimes it gives me only the value without the markup.

```
cell number 1
```

Is there another trick to obtain that easily? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to the fact that the selected node is a textnode.
In this case you want the parentNode.
You may use this to get the node you want:

```
var node = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
node = node.nodeName == "#text" ? node.parentNode : node;
```